# Как при склеивании строки и дробного числа указать формат для числа?

Tags: oracle, форматирование

Есть запрос

```
select arcmat.NAIM_MAT  ,DLINA,SHIRINA,
  CASE WHEN DLINA   IS not NULL and DLINA<>0    THEN (naim_mat||' L='||(DLINA)) end || 
  CASE WHEN SHIRINA IS not NULL and SHIRINA<>0  THEN            ' W='|| SHIRINA end ||''  
as NAIM_MAT_DLINA_SHIRINA      
from arctp left join arcmat on (arctp.id_arcmat=arcmat.id)
order by 2 asc;
```

после его выполнения получается следующее:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В столбце DLINA дробное значение.**

После конкатенации строки со значением этого поля DLINA  (на изображении поле NAIM_MAT_DLINA_SHIRINA) дробные числа отбрасывают нули.

Это не по ГОСТ, поэтому пользователи очень нервничают ))

**Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы нули не отбрасывались?**

---

Вариант решения от @ApInvent я пробовал, но целые числа получают дополнительные  .00 в конце:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Это, как говорят бабульки-пользователи )) не по ГОСТ!

---

надо чтобы 0,25     при склеивании давал 0,25  а не .25

и

надо чтобы 1   при склеивании давал 1,  а не 1.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией [TO_CHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm) и задать с помощью нее [формат](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510) получаемой строки.

Например, результатом такого запроса:

```
select 'L=' || to_char(0.25, '0.99') from dual
```

Будет `L= 0.25`

**UPDATE**

Если количество знаков в числе не известно, то можно указать такой формат:

```
to_char(num, 'FM90.09')
```

Тогда вместо `5` будет `5.0`, вместо `0.25` будет `0.25` и т.д. [Пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/5704).

Если после `5` ноль не нужен, то можно сделать так:

```
rtrim(to_char(num, 'FM90.99'), '.')
```

Тогда вместо `5` будет `5` и т.п. [Пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7/5705).

Ну и дальше уже по необходимости можно добавлять к формату `0` или `9`.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Я так пробовал, но не все так просто.... после такого преобразования к целым числам добавляются .00 Например 5 становится 5.00, а это тоже не по ГОСТ )) и из-за того, что в записи появляется два дополнительных символа, вместо одного недостающего, бабульки-пользователи нервничают еще сильнее )))

Comment: @ВиталийВихляев Дополнил ответ, надеюсь Вам поможет.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ. Работает